# The use of the preposition "with" in context

Tags: prepositions

Tell me please if I need to include the preposition *with* in the following sentence?

> I need something to write (**with**). Could anyone give me a pen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I need something to write with** = I need to write something, but I need something I could use to write that something down on a paper such as a pen on a pencil.

**I need something to write** = I need to write something about something or someone such as a story or an essay.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the same interpretations hold when we rearrange the words of each phrase; that is: _I need to write with something_ means "something like a pen or a pencil," while _I need to write something_ means "something like a short story or essay."

Answer (score -1):

Always use prepositions when in doubt. Yes you do need 'with' here.
The asking for a pen makes the intention clear. A pen wouldn't help you to find something to write 'about'. And if you had meant this then you would have needed the 'about'.

Answer (score -1):

To be grammatically correct, the sentence should read:
I need something with which to write.

In casual, colloquial speech, the "with" has migrated to the end of the sentence. So:
I need something to write with.

Comment: The sentence was grammatically correct in its original version. (For more on this, see, e.g., [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/youve-been-lied-to-heres-why-you-absolutely-can-end-a-sentence-with-a-preposition/), [Your Dictionary](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/prepositions/ending-a-sentence-with-a-preposition.html), [Grammar Girl](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/ending-a-sentence-with-a-preposition) and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/prepositions-ending-a-sentence-with).)